# Third party voice Api integration with twilio

Tags: python, twilio

I want to use third-party voice Api to Twilio for text-to-speech.
I tried several ways but could not find anything. if there's any way I can do it, please help me do it. I saw Twilio's documentation but could not find anything relevant.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The third-party api needs to convert the text and return an audio file such as an MP3 or Wav. Then you use the Twilio [Play](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/play) verb to play the audio file:

```
var response = new VoiceResponse();
response.Play(new Uri("https://third-party-api.com/customaudio.mp3"));
```

The above c# code will produce this Twiml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
     <Play>https://third-party-api.com/customaudio.mp3</Play>
</Response>
```

The Uri in the above example is the link to the audio file produced by the third-party API. Twilio will play this audio file to the caller.

If you are trying to do this in real-time (vs. generating an audio file, storing it, and playing back later), the third-party api must return the audio promptly (less than 12 seconds) or Twilio will timeout and end the call.

I am using a similar approach with [Microsoft Azure Cognitive Services](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/products/cognitive-services/text-to-speech/) for text-to-speech in a real-time IVR. 12 seconds is a Twilio limit but ideally the audio will be returned by the third-party API much quicker so the caller doesn't hang-up because they think they are disconnected.

Comment: @GurujantSingh, glad to help! Please mark this as an answer if it was helpful.